# When I stretch my object its open

Tags: modeling

I have a problem in Blender. When I stretch my object, it opens in 
one spot like that  on the picture. 
Do u know how I can connect the parts together ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fill the hole, or do you want to connect the vertices back together?

Comment: connect together

Comment: already solved it with the help from @kimholder

Comment: remember to mark an answer as accepted if it works for you. Read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

When learning Blender, it is very easy to press one wrong key and have things change in strange and confusing ways. My guess is you accidentally [pressed <kbd>V</kbd>](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=rip), which ripped those vertices, causing the issue you now have when you later scaled or moved those vertices.

To solve this, you need to merge them again. First go to the menus at the bottom of the 3d viewer, and select `Active Element` from the pop-up menu that appears when you click the third field from the left. Now transforms are calculated according to the position of the active selected item, in this case the last vertex you select.

[image]

Now select the 3 vertices that have split open, by pressing <kbd>RMB</kbd> over one, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> over the other two. Select the one where you want the other two to merge to last.

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, and from the pop-up, select `At Last`. The three vertices are now merged into one vertex, at the position of that last vertex.

A good habit when modelling is to try to reduce problems like this by occasionally selecting everything by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>W</kbd> > `Remove Doubles`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals. Also whenever you switch between Edit and Object modes, press <kbd>A</kbd> until you are sure nothing is selected, otherwise the next time you edit that object, you may be changing things you don't realize you have selected.

Comment: thank you ! , yep i think i pressed something without realizing it ^^

Answer (score 0):

With the 3 marked verts

[image]

Select the vert marked 2 and with the magnetic tool on and snap verts selected.

[image]

Snap vert 2 to vert 3. Select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> and click remove doubles

Now Select the vert marked 2 and with the magnetic tool on and snap with marked 1 verts .

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> and click remove doubles

Comment: i dont want to fill it i want to connect them together

Comment: @sawnicrawcer i have edited my answer go through it